# Elastic completion suggester creating inputs

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I have more than 200 000 records so I need to **automatically** create inputs for complete suggester.

I need to get results also for incorrect order ("Potter Harry" instead of "Harry Potter").

Mapping for suggestion:

```
"title_suggest": 
{
   "type": "completion"
}
```

Indexing:

```
{
    "title" : {$title},
    "title_suggest" : 
     {
        "input" : {...},
        "output": {$title}
     }
}
```

Examples:

The simple one:
`"Harry Potter"` has input `{"Harry Potter", "Potter Harry"}`.

But how to create input for long titles? Eg. "*Diary of a modern couple or women are from Venus and men are a moron*"? It makes 1 307 674 368 000 variants of words order.

I hope it is clear what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the suggester. I'm not using Completion Suggester.
I'm using ngrams from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754468/1564987